# Объявление прототипа функции после определения функции в классе с++

Tags: c++, функции, классы

Есть такой код:

```
class Test
{
public:
    void foo()
    {}

    void foo();
};
```

И как вы понимаете он выбрасывает ошибку, только мне не понятно почему? Я посмотрел в стандарте про объявление членов класса, но ничего, что могло бы это запрещать не нашёл. Почему данный код не работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое поведение требуется [согласно §11.1.4/5 [class.mem.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-5):

> (5) A member shall not be declared twice in the member-specification, except that
>
> (5.1) a nested class or member class template can be declared and then later defined, and
> (5.2) an enumeration can be introduced with an opaque-enum-declaration and later redeclared with an enum-specifier.

Чем именно руководствовались авторы стандарта, я, к сожалению, не в курсе.